# Storing inventory for products in noSQL DynamoDB

Tags: database, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm building a PHP based ecommerce platform using Amazon's EC2 and DynamoDB, this is my first experience with a noSQL database and I'm having trouble modeling the tables. I've searched high and low for examples and have come up with nothing.

The main issue I'm facing is storing inventory numbers for any of the possible attributes in the product table. There are a lot more attributes, but I'll keep it simple here.

**PRODUCT TABLE**

- id [455]
- name [Paul Stretch Shirt]
- inPrice [100.00]
- outPrice [200.00]
- color [red, green, blue, white]
- size [XS, S, M, L, XL]

The problem arises when I need to store inventory numbers for any of the multi-valued attributes such as color or size, and I cant find any examples of how to do this. It has to be flexible, so if they only want to track inventory based on size then they can, if they want to track inventory for both size and color then they can. If they don't want to track inventory, it shouldn't matter.

The only simple way I can see of doing it, to keep everything in one table, is to append the quantity numbers to the attribute values using a separator like so, and then use the application logic to handle it.

**PRODUCT TABLE**

- size [XS#1, S#0, M#0, L#1, XL#1]
- color [red#1, green#1, blue#0, white#0]

Is there an alternative way to do this? perhaps with another table, but this seems to be getting into relational territory:

**PRODUCT TABLE**

- color [4, 6, 7, 9]

**INVENTORY TABLE**

- id [4]
- name [Red]
- quantity [1]

Any tips would be great. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Why store the numbers?

Simply insert the products in the Product table.

Use the `Count` every time you need to get the number of records from DynamoDB.